# Can I shift an existing EC2 instance to free-tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made a free tier server on my account and configured it there. Then I had to shift the server to my client's account I made an image of that server and copied it to my client's account so that I wouldn't have to configure all of it again. Turns out it kept all the configurations EXCEPT the free-tier one.

So is there a way for me to make this ec2 instance free tier? Or do I have to build a free tier ec2 from scratch again?

Comment: Free tier is not a configuration item for a server. You can't transfer a "free tier server" to some other AWS account. It's a billing construct, in an AWS account. If you're using an AWS account within the free tier period (first 12 months) then you are not charged for the first 750 hours per month of certain EC2 instance types running certain OSs.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the instance in free tier using AMI(Image of the) as you already have the AMI with you.
And there is no way to move existing instance to free tier,just terminate it after launching the new one in free tier.

Comment: Okay so I started launching an instance and the pre-selected option is t2.micro, which is free-tier. There's no way I would've changed that. And in the invoice, I have been charged for t2.micro as well. Do you have any ideas as to why I got charged in the first place?

Comment: Not sure, but check is 12 months free tier is over ??, and if not then you can ask the same by raising the ticket,as t2.micro is   free in first 12 month and 750 hr of micro instances combined.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount. It is not directly related to specific resources.

Comment: Really? As i am saying to launch instance by selecting free tier resource using existing AMI.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount.

For Amazon EC2, it provides:

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
- 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region

So, each month, any usage that matches the above is not charged (up to the appropriate number of hours). This means you could run one Linux instance for an entire month, or two instances for half a month, or even 30 instances for 1 day.

**You cannot nominate specific resources to be included in the Free Tier.** It is calculated based upon total usage, so might cover multiple EC2 resources.